# C, Refactoring Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, automation, refactoring

My makefile works however if I erase `debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o`
from the target compile, it still works I imagine bc they are done in the other .o targets.

```
Make:    link

compile: listechainee.o debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o

listechainee.o: listechainee.c listechainee.h debutliste.o 
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c listechainee.c
debutliste.o: debutliste.c debutliste.h lecturefichier.o
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c debutliste.c
lecturefichier.o: lecturefichier.c lecturefichier.h statistiques.o
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c lecturefichier.c
statistiques.o: statistiques.c statistiques.h tri.o
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c statistiques.c
tri.o: tri.c  
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c tri.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o 

link: compile
    gcc *.o -o tri
```

If I understand correctly I should delete the `debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o` that are inside the .o targets bc they will be executed as dependencies from the target compile and it should look like this?

```
Make:    link

compile: listechainee.o debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o

listechainee.o: listechainee.c listechainee.h 
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c listechainee.c
debutliste.o: debutliste.c debutliste.h 
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c debutliste.c
lecturefichier.o: lecturefichier.c lecturefichier.h 
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c lecturefichier.c
statistiques.o: statistiques.c statistiques.h 
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c statistiques.c
tri.o: tri.c  
    gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c tri.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o 

link: compile
    gcc *.o -o tri
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I would also recommend using symbols such as `$<`, `$@` and  variables to make it easier to read and understand :)

Comment: @JakubBednarski thanks a lot

Comment: And if you (gnu) make it has a built-in catalog of rules so you only need to specify your dependencies (not how to build it).  You want then set `CFLAGS:=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11`.  Usually, you don't care about changes to .h as it's supposed to be static or corresponding .c file changes.  Then you only need the `compile: ...` line.  Also why do you have both the compile and a  link line, you probably only need the compile just rename the rule to `tri: ...`.  The standard non-file rule is `all` and you specify it as `.PHONY: all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you are using GNU Make, you can simplify your makefile (per above) by relying on the fact it already has a [catalog of rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).  Those rules tells make how to compile c files into object files and how to link object files into a binary.  The recursive flag `-r` for `rm` makes me nervous so I removed it.  You probably don't need a separate link step so I use the standard `all` target instead of `compile`:

```
.PHONY: all clean
CFLAGS:=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11

all: tri

clean:
    rm -f *.o ./tri

tri: listechainee.o debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o

debutliste.o: debutliste.c debutliste.h

lecturefichier.o: lecturefichier.c lecturefichier.h

listechainee.o: listechainee.c listechainee.h

statistiques.o: statistiques.c statistiques.h
```

If you want to be fancy you can use a pattern rule `%.o: %.c %h` that says a given file .o depends on it's corresponding .c and .h files which makes the makefile quite compact:

```
.PHONY: all clean
CFLAGS:=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c11

all: tri

clean:
    rm -f *.o ./tri

tri: listechainee.o debutliste.o lecturefichier.o statistiques.o tri.o

%.o: %.c %h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

The list of object files is probably just all your c files with a different name.  You can write that as:

```
OBJECTS:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

tri: $(OBJECTS)
```

However, I don't usually do that step in my projects as the build now become sensitive to temporary .c files that I often create while working.

Comment: wow super interesting. One question though. Why is that you/I dont need to add the .c to be converted to -o in the CFLAG, how does it know to execute the correct .c file?

Comment: Make knows that it needs to build the missing .o files, and it has a catalog of rules that tells it hat it can build a .o file from a .c file.  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html